# Missing Library from Java Project

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans-7

On the following line:

```
import com.sun.rave.web.ui.appbase.AbstractPageBean;
```

I am receiving the error: "com.sun.rave.web.ui.appbase does not exist" when i hover over it.

```
public class SessionBean1 extends AbstractPageBean {
```

Could the problem be that the program was made with an earlier version of NetBeans and the version I'm using now doesn't support some of the libraries that were used in an earlier version? This was programmed in 7.2 and I'm now using 7.4.

Comment: Context, please. There's [a bug report on an earlier version of NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=189030) of a similar issue, which appears to be some sort of corruption in the NetBeans database; the resolution there was to reinstall NetBeans.

Comment: The bug report is for versions 6.X though, I'm using 7.4 wouldn't the bug have been worked out by then? And what do you mean by context? I'm not sure how to give you context on that lol, it's the error I'm getting on the import when I'm trying to import that package.

Comment: @chrylis I tried reinstalling but am still getting the same error.
The import is being called at the beginning of my class, I've edited my question to show where it's being used.

Comment: Does this problem prevent you from compiling?

Comment: @BrentRobinson yes it does, I get the following error when I try to compile C:\Users\DIR\Documents\NetBeans Projects\Case2Web\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1016: Warning: Could not find file C:\Users\DIR\Documents\NetBeans Projects\Case2Web\${libs.jsf12-support.classpath} to copy.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Answer (score 1):

apparently you need to import the appbase.jar file into your project. ideally through library manager>JSF1.2>Add